# Don't get data to my list from my model (Table)

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

I'm trying to get the data from my database in SQL, I use entity. This is my function in my controller:

```
 public JsonResult getProductCategories()
    {
        List<Categories> category = new List<Categories>();
        using (MasterDetailsEntities1 dc = new MasterDetailsEntities1())
        {
            category = dc.Categories.OrderBy(a => a.CategoryName).ToList(); -- I make a break here and doesn't pass anything and I have data in my table Categories.
        }
        return new JsonResult { Data = category, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

What I want to do is pass all the data from my model or table Categories to the list but it does pass me anything, i'm new doing this I don't know if I'm doing the right way.

This is my model:

```
 public partial class Categories
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Categories()
    {
        this.Products = new HashSet<Products>();
    }

    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Products> Products { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: Your problem is that you end up with empty list in `category` variable or that on returned JSON there is nothing in `Data` property?

Comment: Here it's really uncleared, what you want to do. but assume that you want to get a list of records and save to `List<category>`

Comment: Yes I want to get the data from my database in Categories and save it in my List category. But it doesn't find nothing, its null. And I have data in my table Categories.

Comment: What name has table where you store your `Categories`? Code provided by you should work without problems, unless Entity Framework doesn't know where to look for this data

Comment: The table names is Categories.

Comment: shouldn't it be a return Json(new { Data = category.... rather than return new JsonResult {....?

Comment: I see that to Henry24, but the problem is in categories it doesn't save anything from my table Categories.

Answer (score 0):

So, your problem here is not related to JSON result..it's for db not returning data from the table.

Please check your connection string for the MasterDetailsEntities1 context.
Do you get data from any other table using the same context? Please check.
Nothing looks improper here.